# What's the fastest way to iterate through a dataset and perform calculation on rolling frames of data?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, trading

I wrote a script that logs bitcoin trading data on a 1-second interval. however I need to convert that back into minute-interval tick charts. in the end I'm trying to produce a 60-minute frame of minute-interval ohlcv data for every tick occurred.

Currently, I have something that works as following:

Sample dataset:
[https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1a9d0304ecb9b5d83c6cdca3c5412eaf20221206185100/8033e0](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
klinelog
                    id     close  volume  unique_tick
------------------------------------------------------
0        1664553541000 19734.530   4.960         True
1        1664553542000 19734.530   4.960        False
2        1664553543000 19731.480   9.929         True
3        1664553544000 19731.480   9.929        False
4        1664553545000 19737.200   6.023         True
...                ...       ...     ...          ...
2678395  1667231936000 20388.820  10.606         True
2678396  1667231937000 20388.820  10.606        False
2678397  1667231938000 20388.430   5.729         True
2678398  1667231939000 20388.430   5.729        False
2678399  1667231940000 20388.220   6.613         True
```

```
for i in range(len(klinelog)):
    # CHECK TO SEE IF THE SECOND DATA IS A UNIQUE TICK
    if klinelog['unique_tick'].iloc[i] == True:
        # GRAB 60MIN OF SECOND DATA
        try:
            kline_combined = klinelog.iloc[i:(i + 3600)].copy().drop('unique_tick', axis=1)
        except:
            continue

        # PROCESS INTO 60MIN OF MINUTE OHLCV DATA
        kline_combined['open'] = kline_combined['close']
        kline_combined['high'] = kline_combined['close']
        kline_combined['low'] = kline_combined['close']
        kline_combined = kline_combined.groupby(np.arange(len(kline_combined)) // 60).agg({'id': 'min', 'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last', 'volume': 'sum'})
```

However since I'm dealing with months/years of data, this would take days to complete. is there any way to do this without iterating over the entire dataset?

Comment: So If I understand your code right, do you want to make ~1.25 millions of new dataframes? This will be always slow.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. unfortuanately, yes and possibly feeding all those data into a machine learning model :( i could split the data and do multiprocessing but that's not really a solution. can i get rid of iloc and make this into vectorization?